# nonzero width non-joiner non-breaking space character

Tags: url, unicode

Is there any space unicode character which and be used in URL. In terms of [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Spaces_in_Unicode) is there a **non-zero** width non-joiner non-breaking space character?

Answer (score 1):

Any space character can be used in a URL, but only as %-encoded, e.g. `%20` for the common U+0020 SPACE and `%C2%A0` for U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE. For SPACE, this is a specific requirement in the Internet-standard for URLs. Other space characters are outside Ascii, and all non-Ascii characters must be %-encoded.

See [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)